# Existe uma maneira melhor de lidar com banco de dados relacionais e não relacionais no mesmo projeto?

Tags: mysql, python, orientação-a-objetos, mongodb, sqlalchemy

Estou refatorando um código, onde eu trato uns dados e mando-os para um banco de dados. Eu tenho duas versões. Uma onde uso MongoDB e outra onde uso Mysql. Mas eu gostaria de juntar as duas versões(tem muito código duplicado) e estava pensando como poderia fazer isso. Abaixo segue um pedaço do código onde eu crio uma classe Update que herda ou de BancoDeDadosMongoDB ou de BancoDeDadosSQL. Minha idéia era botar esse esquema em todas as classes que fazem conexão com o banco de dados.

Existe uma maneira melhor de fazer isso? O que vocês acham ? Seria melhor fazer duas versões separadas? Uma pro MongoDB e outra pro Mysql ?

```
class Update(BancoDeDadosMongoDB):
    def __init__():
        self.db = super().__init__()
            
    def check_update_date():
        #Checa se o banco de dados escolhido 
        if issuclass(Update,BancoDeDadosMongoDB):
            #Faz a busca na coleção atualização
            result = self.db.atualizacaofind(
                {'ultima_atualizacao':{'$regex': '\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d'}},
                {'_id':0}
                )
            return result
        
        if issubclass(Update,BancoDeDadosSQL):
            #Preciso ajeitar essa busca para buscar pela data de atualização.
            #Primeiro preciso ver como ficará organizado a tabela no BD relacional
            
            empresa =self.session.query(Config).filter(Config.ultima_atualizacao.like('\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d')):
            
            return result
```

Answer (score 5):

A ideia é você criar uma interface, e nessa interface você define as operações que vão existir para dois bancos, como update, create, getById e etc. Você deve usar um repository para cada objeto do dominio, em outras palavras, para cada entidade ou tabela do banco.

A partir dai, você cria uma classe para cada banco e implementa essa interface, ou seja, vai implementar essas funções que você definiu (update, create, getById). Algo da seguinte forma:

```
class Interface_UsuarioRepository:
    # assinaturas
    update()
    create()
    getById(Id)


class UsuarioMongoDBImpl(Interface_UsuarioRepository):
    def update(): 
        # implementação do método update para o banco MongoDB
        ...


class UsuarioMySQLImpl (Interface_UsuarioRepository): 
    def update(): 
       # implementação do método update para o banco MySQL
       ...
```

E depois disso, ao invés de utilizar diretamente a implementação você irá usar o principio da inversão de depedência para depender apenas da abstração, que nesse caso é a interface UsuarioRepository. Algo nesse sentido:

```
class Usuario:
   _repository: Interface_UsuarioRepository
   # /* CONSTRUTOR DA CLASSE Usuario */
   def __init__(self, repository):
       self._repository = repository

    
    def updateUser(self):
        self._repository.update()
```

Dessa forma, quando você quiser alterar entre um banco e o outro é necessário apenas instanciar a classe **Usuario** com **UsuarioMySQLImpl** para o **Mysql** ou **UsuarioMongoDBImpl** para **MongoDB**. Exemplo:

```
usuario = Usuario(UsuarioMySQLImpl());
# Essa função vai ser executada com o banco Mysql
usuario.updateUser();

usuario = Usuario(UsuarioMongoDBImpl());
# Essa função vai ser executada com o banco MongoDB
usuario.updateUser();
```

Da uma olhada nesse padrão repositório (*repository pattern*) e procura como implementar isso em python. Eu misturei um pouco a sintaxe do Java com outras linguagens, espero que tenha ao menos dado um caminho para você resolver seu problema.

Comment: Oi - eu iria responder basicamente a mesma coisa  - tomei a liberdade de editar seu pseudo-codigo para ficar "pseudo código em Python". (A maior diferença é que Python não tem "interfaces" nativas - o substituto mais comum é herança múltipla mesmo, embora nesse exemplo nem seja necessário)

Comment: O que dá pra acrescentar é que em Python, sendo bem tranquila a introspecção é fácil fazer as itnerfaces para SQL e MongoDB serem "genéricas" e introspectarem os campos (e nome da tabela/collection) na classe pai (e aí pra evitar uma camada muito mágica o melhor é que os métodos do repositório recebam o objeto pai explicitamente)

Comment: Sua edição foi super bem-vinda, me faltou skills em Python para construir um exemplo nela :D.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, @jsbueno !!! Ajudou sim , e muito!

Answer (score 2):

(Mais um no *hype* do MongoDB que ninguém precisa em 99% dos casos... deve ser só para praticar o conceito ).

O que vai ser gravado nos dois casos são estruturas distintas, no caso do relacional em particular vai ser gravado algo em uma combinação de tabelas que depende da regra de negócio, digo, de cada tipo de conteúdo a ser gravado a cada momento no código. Então acredito que não dá para extrair um caso geral que sirva para todas as situações no código, se tentar não vai ficar legal. Para buscas vai ser a mesma coisa, os critérios de busca eu acredito que vão dar diferença de um para o outro.

Vou falar do Java, o que o pessoal faz quando o banco é relacional devido à questão da impedância objeto-relacional é trabalhar com objetos no código e, das duas uma, ou faz a conversão explícita para SQL na mão (usando JDBC) ou mapeia de forma mais configurativa e automatizada usando uma ferramenta de ORM (como JPA com Hibernate). Isso permite usar uma API que você manda persistir um objeto de certo tipo e ele faz a conversão. É interessante abstrair isso em um padrão Repository, que é simplesmente tentar fornecer uma classe que você usa como se fosse um contêiner de objetos em memória, como uma lista ou dicionário, com seus métodos particulares para adicionar, remover e localizar objetos daquele tipo (no caso do repositório são típicos certos métodos do tipo find, como findById, findAll) mas por debaixo do pano está sendo feita a persistência desses objetos em banco que no código estão sendo tratados como sendo salvos em um contêiner. Note que vai ser um repositório para cada tipo de objeto/situação no código que requer persistência de dados, e as operações que ele fornece também vão ser caso-a-caso. Espera-se também que essa interface fornecida pelo repositório seja agnóstica ao tipo de banco (por exemplo, não suporte features que só estão presentes em um ou outro tipo de banco).

Mas me parece que nada disso vai ser útil no seu caso. A resposta do Leandro Souza diz que é, mas não tenho certeza. Parece que vai porque está sendo sugerido implementar de um jeito diferente para cada tipo de repositório que é necessário, ou seja, para cada situação no código, aí acredito que daria, mas eu entendi que não é o que você estava imaginando na sua pergunta, você queria um aproveitamento de código ainda maior. Se entendi errado, então essa proposta do Repository deve funcionar.

Para uma discussão um pouco mais detalhada dos contras de se ter um caso geral de persistência para relacional e não-relacional (em inglês), veja: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31941038/2241463